# load with order when using includes clause in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I need to do the following:

I have a huge list of IDs (called user_ids).

I would like to pull all the users where :id => user_ids, and include the photos model as well. However, I would like the photos model to be sorted by created_at (because I need to know the date of the first photo the user has posted to our site).

So basically, I'd like to do:

```
User.includes(:photos).order(:created_at).where(:id => user_ids).each do |user|
  user.photos.first
  ...
```

to get the first photo the user has published. right now, the order clause is referring to the User model and not the Photo model.

I'm not sure how to order when using the includes clause. I also don't know if there's a better way of going about this!

any ideas? worst case, if I need to use plain postgres, I am happy to do that as well - but no ideas on how to approach that either, all my ideas are extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the table to order by using `table_name.column_name` in the order clause:

```
User.includes(:photos).order('photos.created_at').where(:id => user_ids)
```